# I am getting IllegalArgumentException during picking a document file from download manager ,which is happening only for oreo

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-8.0-oreo, android-download-manager

Here I am attaching the logs :

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/1587
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
```

I am using this code which is working fine.But for the case of download manager it is throwing exception at first line of 'try' block

```
 Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
```

I already tried this: [Android getting file path from content URI using contentResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153170/android-getting-file-path-from-content-uri-using-contentresolver)
and this: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446927/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unknown-uri-content) and some others related to this question but not any one of them resolves my problem.

Comment: Are you getting all the things required in the line `query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);` ?

Comment: uri , projection i am sending but selection and selctionArgs are null, i don't think that will create problem

Comment: Seems like your URI is invalid.

Comment: yeah i know ,but how come this is working fine for other versions

Comment: I think the best option would be to use DocumentTree

Comment: @AjayChauhan Did you get any solution? Please help me out for the same. I'm also getting the same error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was getting the same error `Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads`. I managed to solve this by changing contentUri and by using `InputStream` methods to fetch file from Download directory. In some of devices changing contentUri to `content://downloads/my_downloads` works. [Checkout this answer for full solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021624/5996106).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you also only get this on devices running 8.0? I recently started getting this in crashlytics with devices running 8.0

Comment: Yes, this issue is from android 8.0

Comment: I am facing this issue with Flutter Image picker. How can this be solved?

Comment: You have to manually change couple of lines of code in Image picker by yourself as described in link in answer.

Comment: I created a gist that fixes this issue - https://gist.github.com/HBiSoft/15899990b8cd0723c3a894c1636550a8

Comment: @HB. your gist code works fine in all devices. thanks.

Comment: I'm getting error in a variable 'filename' around line 94. :(

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury error is fixed, commenting to let other know it is working (tested 08.01.20)